# Не появляется диалоговое окно

Tags: java, android

при вызывании диалогового окна экран просто немного затемняется, но не появляется окно.

Вот вызов окна:

```java
public class AdminPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        boolean f = false;
        int idS = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        Log.i(TAG, "It`s onSwipe" + idS);
        DialogFragment DialogFragment = new DialogFragment();
        DialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),null);

        //SQLiteDatabase db = workBD.getReadableDatabase();
        //db.execSQL("DELETE FROM workers WHERE _id = " + id.get(idS));
        b = true;
        getList();
    }
    ...
}
```

и класс отвечающий за диалоговое окно:

```java
public class DalogFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    AdminPage adminPage;

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        adminPage = new AdminPage();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        return builder
                .setMessage("Подтвердить удаление?")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.warning)
                .setTitle("Вы собираетесь удалить работника")
                .setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        adminPage.Delete();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Нет", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                })
                .create();
    }
}
```

Comment: вы хотите вызвать простой диалог или диалоговый фрагмент? потому что сейчас вы вызываете диалоговый фрагмент из которого вызывается диалог

Comment: Ваш класс называется `DalogFragment`, а вы создаете экземпляпр класса `DialogFragment`

Comment: Исправил, но всё равно тот же результат. Хочу просто вызвать окно где можно нажать да или нет